# Можно ли сменить стартовую страницу в Angular?

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-studio, angular2

Приложение на Angular стартует с Index.html.

Это какое-то жесткое соглашение или где-то можно задать, что бы приложение открывалось со страницы с другим именем?

Вопроса интереса ради.

Comment: [почему вы не хотите гуглить?](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) в `options.apps` же все детально описано

Comment: @overthesanity гуглил, но сюда меня ссылка не привела=( Оформите ответом.

Comment: вряд ли простая ссылка считается ответом :)) 